# Changing colour range in dropdown

Tags: dropdown, plotly-python, choropleth

I am trying to create a choropleth with dropdown. I want to change colour scale with dropdown buttons, like min and max for each button. my recent scale is between 0 , 50 M. it makes sense for some buttons but for button A, it doesnt make any sense

thanks in advance

> from urllib.request import urlopen import json with
> urlopen("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Babolius/project/62fef3b31fa9e34afb055e493de107d89a50a889/tr-cities-utf8.json")
> as response:
> id = json.load(response) import pandas as pd df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Babolius/project/main/komisyon5.csv",encoding
> ='utf8', dtype={"Toplam": int}) df.groupby(['ID']).sum()
>
> import plotly.express as px
>
> fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, geojson= id, locations= 'ID', color=
> "Toplam",
> color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
> range_color=(0, 10000000),
> mapbox_style="carto-darkmatter",
> zoom=3, center = {"lat": 41.0902, "lon": 28.7129},
> opacity=0.5,
> )
>
> dropdown_buttons =[{'label': 'A', 'method' : 'restyle', 'args': [{'z':
> [df["A"]]}, {'visible': [True, False, False, False, False, False]},
> {'title': 'A'}]},
> {'label': 'B', 'method' : 'restyle', 'args': [{'z': [df["B"]]}, {'visible': [False, True, False, False, False, False]},
> {'title': 'B'}]},
> {'label': 'C', 'method' : 'restyle', 'args': [{'z': [df["C"]]}, {'visible': [False, False, True, False, False, False]},
> {'title': 'C'}]},
> {'label': 'D', 'method' : 'restyle', 'args': [{'z': [df["D"]]}, {'visible': [False, False, False, True, False, False]},
> {'title': 'D'}]},
> {'label': 'E', 'method' : 'restyle', 'args': [{'z': [df["E"]]}, {'visible': [False, False, False, False, True, False]},
> {'title': 'E'}]},
> {'label': 'Toplam', 'method' : 'restyle', 'args': [{'z': [df["Toplam"]]}, {'visible': [False, False, False, False,
> False, True]}, {'title': 'Toplam'}]}]
>
> fig.update_layout({'updatemenus':[{'type': 'dropdown', 'showactive':
> True, 'active': 0, 'buttons': dropdown_buttons}]})
>
> fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0}) fig.show()

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than i thought

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Babolius/project/62fef3b31fa9e34afb055e493de107d89a50a889/tr-cities-utf8.json") as response:
    id = json.load(response)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Babolius/project/main/komisyon5.csv",encoding ='utf8', dtype={"Toplam": int})
df.groupby(['ID']).sum()


import plotly.express as px


fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, geojson= id, locations= 'ID', color= "Toplam",
                           color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                           color_discrete_sequence=(min, max),
                           mapbox_style="carto-darkmatter",
                           zoom=3, center = {"lat": 41.0902, "lon": 28.7129},
                           opacity=0.5,
                          )

dropdown_buttons =[{'label': 'A', 'method' : 'update', 'args': [{'z': [df["A"]]}, {'visible': [True, False, False, False, False, False]}, {'title': 'A'}]},
                   {'label': 'B', 'method' : 'update', 'args': [{'z': [df["B"]]}, {'visible': [False, True, False, False, False, False]}, {'title': 'B'}]},
                   {'label': 'C', 'method' : 'update', 'args': [{'z': [df["C"]]}, {'visible': [False, False, True, False, False, False]}, {'title': 'C'}]},
                   {'label': 'D', 'method' : 'update', 'args': [{'z': [df["D"]]}, {'visible': [False, False, False, True, False, False]}, {'title': 'D'}]},
                   {'label': 'E', 'method' : 'update', 'args': [{'z': [df["E"]]}, {'visible': [False, False, False, False, True, False]}, {'title': 'E'}]},
                   {'label': 'Toplam', 'method' : 'restyle', 'args': [{'z': [df["Toplam"]]}, {'visible': [False, False, False, False, False, True]}, {'title': 'Toplam'}]}]

fig.update_layout({'updatemenus':[{'type': 'dropdown', 'showactive': True, 'active': 0, 'buttons': dropdown_buttons}]})

fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```